# Generic `update` controller overwrite for active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have the following method in my ActiveAdmin DSL to show any validation errors at the top:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  # ...

  controller do
    def update
      super do |format|
        flash[:alert] = @category.errors.to_a.join('. ') unless  @category.errors.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am specifically using `@category` in this case. I am wondering, if there is an elegant way to get the "current" object for any model that I am editing.

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

ActiveAdmin uses InheritedResources inside, so you can use `resource`

```
resource        #=> @project
collection      #=> @projects
resource_class  #=> Project
```

https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources